# form_for - if signed in do one thing if not do another logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form that posts something to a feed.  I would like an user to post to the feed if they are signed in, but if they are not and they hit submit, I would like them to see the login modal.  Here is my current form without this logic.  It's a basic form_for - nothing special.

```
<%= form_for(@sub_opp) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sport, :class=>'form_label' %>
    <%= f.select :sport, ['Basketball', 'Beach Volleyball', 'Flag Football'] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id = "datetime_select">
    <%= f.label :Sub_Date, :class=>'form_label' %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :sub_time, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'POST', :class=>"btn btn-success btn-large" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Conceptually, I would like to incorporate logic in along these lines when one clicks the submit button.

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
     Submit the form
   Otherwise
     <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
```

Can you do this with a form_for?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a simple if / then statement.  Surprised i did not think of this earlier.  Thanks.

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.hidden_field :poster_user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'POST', :class=>"btn btn-success btn-large" %>
 </div>
<%else%>
 <div class="actions">
  <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal", class ="btn btn-success btn-large">POST</a>
 </div>
<%end%>
```